# Is this normal for a python program to stop on windows after several hours?

Tags: windows-8.1, python

I'm running a script of my own on windows 8.1 in python 2.7 on a laptop.
This laptop is always plugged in and I change the power setting for it to never go into sleep mode.

I have a script that make a search every 3 minutes on a popular second hand sells website and emails me each time their is something meeting my criteria.

It's a `while True:` loop, it's never suposed to stop, it says what it's doing but at some point it just freezes.

Thanks.

Comment: So did you try to figure out why it freezes? Lack of resources? Some error message or anything?

Comment: no error, the text in the console just stops during the loop.

It can't be lack of ressources this is a 16GB, quad core@2.5Ghz laptop.

Comment: No, it is not normal for a Python program to stop on Windows after several hours.

Comment: What text? Why could it not be a lack of resources? Did you actually check the utilization? Depending on how you handle your stuff there might be no Garbage to collect. Also you might just be banned from the site for while. Your network might be down or there might be some form of resource log. Did you try to debug in either of those directiosn?

Comment: I saw it stop, everything looked fine in the task manager (for ram and cpu usage). I was not banned and network was not down since I could still access it via my browser.